# Error: Member not found: 'ImageCropper.cropImage'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

**i spent all night trying get cropped image, need some help **

```
  image_cropper: ^1.5.0 # Used to Crop/Rotate Selected images from user's device
```

///Error

> Error: Member not found: 'ImageCropper.cropImage'.
> final croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(

///images_source

```
class ImageSourceSheet extends StatelessWidget {
  // Constructor
  ImageSourceSheet({required this.onImageSelected});

  // Callback function to return image file
  final Function(File?) onImageSelected;
  // ImagePicker instance
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future<void> selectedImage(BuildContext context, File? image) async {
    // init i18n
    final i18n = AppLocalizations.of(context);

    // Check file
    if (image != null) {
      final croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
          sourcePath: image.path,
          aspectRatioPresets: [CropAspectRatioPreset.square],
          maxWidth: 400,
          maxHeight: 400,
          androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
            toolbarTitle: i18n.translate("edit_crop_image"),
            toolbarColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
          ));
      onImageSelected(croppedImage);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `ImageCropper().cropImage(...)`.

```dart
final croppedImage = await ImageCropper().cropImage(....)
```

You can check [example code](https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper/example).